# Destroy Superfish plugin

Tags: 7, javascript, navigation

I have the Superfish module on my site that my main navigation uses. The site I am building is responsive so I'd like to destroy Superfish when the viewport is smaller than a specific size.

I see that superfish has a destroy method: `example.superfish('destroy');`

How can I use this method on my nav menu in Drupal? I'm assuming I need to do something like...

```
Drupal.behaviors.superfish {something here}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I think this is not possible: The `destroy()` method was implemented in the Superfish jQuery plugin since version 1.7, but the Superfish module uses version 1.4.8 of Superfish jQuery plugin.

Comment: 2019 – Still1.4.8 in the 7.x branch.